# Using Collcetions in Meteor JS?

Tags: collections, meteor

My requirement is :

I need to store all the details about a person manually by (for example)Admin.

- Which Collection usage is best for above requirement means using Predefined Collection Accounts or User Defined Collection?
- My Doubt is : If using Accounts package must be used password but my requirement doesn't contains password only person details.So what i can do for this problem using Accounts?
- In case using User Defined Collection then how to provide security for this?

I didn't get any idea about this problem.So please suggest me what to do?

Comment: You want security but no passwords? Could you expand on what exactly you're trying to do? It sounds like you want to have a user log in, and then maintain a list of people who are *not* users of the application. Is this correct? No matter what, you should *never* store passwords in clear text. They should always be hashed, which the `accounts-password` package does in a proven, secure way.

Comment: Yes,i want to have a user log in, and then maintain a list of people.Exactly i needed this.Can you please give me suggestions for this problem which collection is best?.@Cuberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a collection, called something like `"people"`, `"customers"`, `"students"`, etc (whatever makes sense for your particular use case). There are several important things you need to do to make it secure:

- Use the built in `accounts-password` package to have your user log in to maintain the list.
- Remove the `insecure` and `autopublish` packages.
- Conditionally publish the relevant fields of the `people` collection, only to your authorized user.
- Set allow and deny rules for inserting/updating/removing people documents. Your rules should check that the user is authorized.
- Do not store sensitive information like passwords, credit card numbers, social security numbers, etc in clear text in your database.
- Use SSL.
- Read and watch these two links, where Emily Stark discusses security (specifically content security policies) in Meteor:

  https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/10/27/defense-in-depth-securing-meteor-apps-with-content-security-policy

  https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/08/02/meteor-devshop-6-devshop-live-security-meteor-ui
- Remember that no matter what framework/system you use, there is no such thing as absolute, 100% security. You must use defense in depth to achieve the best possible security that you can.